# Find out the code in SensorManager functions

Tags: android, orientation, accelerometer, gyroscope, sensor-fusion

Is it possible to know how the following functions are implemented.

```
public void calculateAccMagOrientation() 
{
    if(SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accel, magnet)) 
    {
        SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, accMagOrientation);
    }
}
```

So is it possible to know how the functions `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix` and `SensorManager.getOrientation`.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, are you asking for the source code of SensorManager ?

Comment: Yeah, source code for `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix` and `SensorManager.getOrientation`.

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources are off-topic for StackOverflow. Especially if that resource is easily available. What do you get when you type your above comment in Google Search ?

Comment: My bad. But I did that immediately after your first reply and I managed to find it. Thanks :)